# Pure CSS spinner freezes

Tags: javascript, css, angular, spinner

I have a pure CSS spinner that I want to show while my JavaScript is doing other work (an async call and then iterating through an array of about 10,000 elements).  The spinner appears at the right time but freezes when a certain point in the code is hit.  In the code below, the `console.log`s for the 'one', 'two', and 'three' happen basically instantly - then there is a long pause (which is when my spinner freezes) then 'four' and 'five' log out together and my content loads.  So basically I know that the code between the "`console.log('three')`" and "`console.log('four')`":

```
// for search bar
search(text) {
  this.searching = true;  // shows spinner
  console.log('one');
  var text = text.toUpperCase();

  // search the text with an api call
  this.securitiesService.searchSecurities(text)
  .subscribe(data => {
    var response = data.response;
    console.log('two');

    // if no search results are present go to correct page
    if (!response.length) {
      this.router.navigate(...to route...);
      return;
    }

    console.log('three');

    // FREEZES HERE !!!
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      if (text === response[i].ticker) {

        // UNFREEZES HERE !!!
        console.log('four');
        this.router.navigate(...to route...);
        this.searching = false;
        console.log('five');
        return;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This happens with every pure CSS spinner I try.

Am I wrong in thinking that my JavaScript shouldn't freeze my pure CSS spinner?  Why would the code freeze it?

Comment: only the spinner? anything else? maybe the whole browser?

Comment: Have you tried disabling javascript to see if the spinner freezes?

Comment: Is it same in all browsers? May be comparing its efficiency in different browsers will give you a perspective.

Comment: You're freezing the Renderer by using that for loop. `response.find(x =>  x.ticker === text)` will be much better than looping.

Comment: Looking at your code it seems that you are expecting only one record that matches the condition `(text === response[i].ticker)`. In that case returning 10000 records from async call is not an efficient way. It will be better if you update the async API, if you have control on it. If not, @Brandon's response should help you.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript runs on the UI thread, so it will still block CSS-only spinners. You need to move the work off the UI thread or split it up so the UI has time to update.

Depending on which browsers you need to support, you might be able to use Web Workers. See http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20workers for browser support or http://www.html5hacks.com/blog/2012/09/22/web-workers-basics-of-the-web-browsers-ui-thread/ for examples.

You can also process one (or 10 or 100) records at a time and call each "batch" within `window.setTimeout` or `window.requestAnimationFrame`. Try something like this (*code not tested*):

```
// for search bar
search(text) {
    this.searching = true;  // shows spinner
    console.log('one');
    var text = text.toUpperCase();

    // search the text with an api call
    this.securitiesService.searchSecurities(text)
        .subscribe(data => {
            var response = data.response;
            console.log('two');

            // if no search results are present go to correct page
            if (!response.length) {
                this.router.navigate(...to route...);
                return;
            }

            console.log('three');

            var i = 0;
            var self = this;
            var processBatch = function () {
                if (text === response[i].ticker) {
                    console.log('four');
                    self.router.navigate(...to route...);
                    self.searching = false;
                    console.log('five');
                    return;
                }
                if (++i < response.length) {
                    window.setTimeout(processBatch, 0);
                }
            };
            window.setTimeout(processBatch, 0);
        });
}
```

If you want to process more than one item per batch, you can have a loop within `processBatch` that iterates through a small number of items.

**Side note:** See @gelliott181's comment above if `data.response` is a string.